# Incompatible types error when iterating through enum elements to create new object

Tags: java, for-loop, enums

I am trying to use two enums to create a deck of cards via a 2d array, then print all of the created cards.

```
public class Deck {

private Card[][] cards;

public Deck() {
  cards = new Card[4][13];
  for (Card.Suit suit : Card.Suit.values()) {
     for (Card.Rank rank : Card.Rank.values()) {
        //This is where my problem begins
        cards[suit][rank] = new Card(suit, rank);
     }
  }
}



public Card getCard(Card.Suit s, Card.Rank r) {
   //The error appears here as well.
   return cards[suit][rank];
}
```

Here are the enums I'm trying to use.

```
public class Card {
   private Rank rank;
   private Suit suit;

   // Kinds of suits
   public enum Suit {
      CLUBS,
      DIAMONDS,
      HEARTS,
      SPADES;
   }

   // Kinds of ranks
   public enum Rank {
      ACE,
      DEUCE,
      THREE,
      FOUR,
      FIVE,
      SIX,
      SEVEN,
      EIGHT,
      NINE,
      TEN,
      JACK,
      QUEEN,
      KING;
   }

   public Card(Suit s, Rank r) {
      rank = r;
      suit = s;
   }
...}
```

What I think should be happening is that the for loop is going through each element via Card.Suit.values() and then Card.Rank.values() and creating a new Card(Suit suit, Rank rank), according to it's index in the array cards[s][r].

When I compile my code it gives the error.

"Deck.java:42: error: incompatible types: Suit cannot be converted to int

cards[suit][rank] = new Card(suit, rank);"

Comment: Yes, indices of an array are integers, starting from 0. Not suits or ranks. That's what the error tells you. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: suit is an object of an enum, not an integer. you have to fetch your desired enum value from suit object and apply ordinal method so that you can get the index as an integer value.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, the .ordinal() suggestion works perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexes in arrays need to be integers, but at line `cards[suit][rank] = ...` you are passing enum constant held by `suit` (like `CLUBS`) and `rank`. You can get int representing *position* of current enum constant with [`Enum#ordinal()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal--) method.

Change your

```
cards[suit][rank] = new Card(suit, rank);
```

to

```
cards[suit.ordinal()][rank.ordinal()] = new Card(suit, rank);
//        ^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your explanation, this worked perfectly!